# Bluetooth Reliability

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

I am installing ubuntu and I need a reliable Bluetooth connection.

Do I install 22.0.4 or go further back to 20.04.

I remember having Bluetooth issues with 22.04 last year but these may have been resolved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)